# How to exclude storybook files from final bundle

Tags: vue.js, webpack, storybook

I'm using a storybook.js to document Vue components in a Vue project. I don't want to include the storybook documentation files in the final build.

I've tried tapping copy plugin to ignore *.stories.js. But it's still including content of `*.stories.js` files into some `chunk.js`

```
 /** vue.config.js **/
...
 chainWebpack: config => {
        ...

        config.plugin('copy').tap(([options]) => {
            options[0].ignore.push('*.stories.js')
            return [options]
        })
    }
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The copy plugin is used for static files, there must be another configuration for webpack. I tried adding `exclude` to rules but it doesn't work either.